# Get New Co-Ordinate based on degrees and distance

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, math

I have a coordinate from Core Location and want to calculate the co-ordinate given a bearing and a distance, say in km.

I think this is the formula from here.
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

> Formula:
>   lat2 =
>   asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d/R) +
>   cos(lat1)*sin(d/R)*cos(θ))
>   lon2 =
>   lon1 +
>   atan2(sin(θ)*sin(d/R)*cos(lat1),
>   cos(d/R)−sin(lat1)*sin(lat2))
>   d/R is
>   the angular distance (in radians),
>   where d is the distance travelled and
>   R is the earth’s radius

I have the following code.

```
     CLLocationCoordinate2D linecoordstart;
     linecoordstart = [[existingpoints objectAtIndex:i] coordinate];
     NSString *bearing = [[existingpoints objectAtIndex:i] heading];
     NSString *distance = [[existingpoints objectAtIndex:i] distance];
CLLocationCoordinate2D sourceCoordinate;
                sourceCoordinate = [[existingpoints objectAtIndex:i] coordinate];


NSLog(@"%f,%f",sourceCoordinate.latitude,sourceCoordinate.longitude);
   float lat2;
int d = 5;
int R = 6371;
lat2 = asin(sin(sourceCoordinate.latitude)cos(d/R) + cos(sourceCoordinate.latitude)sin(d/R)cos(180));
NSLog(@"%f",lat2);
```

I want to be able to pass it a bearing which is currently an NSString and the distance.  I cannot work out how to use the Math.h functions for the life of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from `NSString` to a number you can use:

```
NSString* intNum = @"123";
NSString* floatNum = @"123.456";
int iv = [intNum intValue];
float fv = [floatNum floatValue];
```

Also, both `d` and `R` are defined as `int` (instead of `float`). In your code `d/R` will clip the value to integer 0. Might want to make them `float` (and initialize them with float values).